# Storing logs in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm forced to store my NodeJS application's logs in a PostgreSQL database. The application's quite small.

Naturally, logs are less structured than my usual data, and data without rigid structure doesn't work well with SQL databases.

**How could I approach storing JSON logs in a SQL database to make it as efficient as possible?** What tricks could I use?

The solutions I see myself:

- Dump all JSON as strings into one column, parse it with something else.
- Declare columns for properties logged objects always will have. Dump the rest into another column (i.e. `column "Event", column "Subtype", column "Time", column "Other"`).

Please let me know of any SQL features I should look at to make it easier.
I'm a bit of a database layman, so any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Put the JSON log into a `jsonb` column?

Comment: Any SQL database with decent JSON support can act as a NOSQL database.

Comment: Dump it into a `json`/`jsonb` column, make a interesting properties available through a `view`.

Comment: @JohnSmith logs are static/historical data. so you need only `insert`(you don't need any `transactions`/updates for specific record etc. just take  [clickhouse](https://clickhouse.yandex/#performance) and forget all problems. you'll have amazing performance and compression, auto partitioning and other features.